# What is the formula for calculating the change in position of an animated object in relationship to change in distance? (Parallax)

Tags: animation, math, parallax

I am trying to create a parallax animation with multiple objects in the scene that have a different distance to the observer(me) for 3-d effect, but i don`t know how to accurately calculate the relationship of change in speed and size to distance.

Comment: Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yeh you right, but i thought that a lot of js developers have confronted this problem before and know the answer

Comment: The "problem" is not clearly defined at the text of the Question.

Comment: Are you comfortable with vectors?

Comment: @Beta i no mathematician but i have studied some linear algebra for data science so i think it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to approach this question with the difference of displacement rather then speed. So lets say the distance to the first object is 200px. It`s size is going to be

```
Size = original_size * 1/distance
```

So when the object at distance with no distance is going to be displaced by it`s original size, the object with distance 250px is going to be displayed by

```
Displacement = original_size(px) * 1/250(px)
```

So to get the per pxl change in distance

```
PerPxlChange = (Displacement(original) - Displacement(250px))/Displacement(original)
```

And then just multiply the change per pxl by the change in position in original object.